# How to animate with single key press using Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a cube move in a direction smoothly like an animation but with only a single key press. I've been only able to create animation while holding down the key.

Here's some code I've been using:

```
<script>
    function init() {
... other code needed ....
            document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);
                    };

            function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
                var key = event.which; 
                if (key == 37) {
                    leftAnimation();     
                }
            };
            function leftAnimation() {
                var timer = 0.0001 * Date.now();
                for(var v = 0; v < 10; v++){
                    cube.position.x = Math.cos(timer) * v;
                }
                animate();       
            }
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                render();
            };
            function render() {
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
            init();
            animate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `leftAnimation()` will run only once running the entire internal loop before the frame is updated resulting in that the cube just will appear to nudge, not animate.

You could use a fixed motion vector instead initialized to for example `null`. Then when the key is pressed initialize it with the x/y[/z] direction you want to move the cube.

Meanwhile add the current vector to the cube's position when it's not `null`.

For example:

```
// code initialized at this point ...

// vector for motion
var vector = null;

// key handler
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {             // left
    vector = {x: -0.02, y: 0, z: 0};  // fixed vector
  }
};

(function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  render();
  if (vector) {  // any vector set? if so update position with vector deltas
    cubeMesh.position.x += vector.x;
    cubeMesh.position.y += vector.y;
    cubeMesh.position.z += vector.z;
  }
})();

// render functions here etc. ...
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/ka6g98b9/)

An alternative is to use an accumulated vector pre-initialized with 0s where the keys add or subtract to the vector - this allow you to "nudge" the speed in the directions you want:

```
// vector for motion
var vector = {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0};

// key handler
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {       // left
    vector.x -= 0.002;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 39) {  // right
    vector.x += 0.002;
  }
};

(function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  render();
  cubeMesh.position.x += vector.x;
  cubeMesh.position.y += vector.y;
  cubeMesh.position.z += vector.z;
})();
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/k8zk3omr/)

A little more than you asked about, just to give a better insight of the idea - you can simply use a single x variable/constant for that matter if you only want to start moving in x direction. Adopt as needed.